# Is there a way to get the colour of a tkinter square?

Tags: python, tkinter

If you set up a rectangle or square in tkinter, is there a way to get the colour of that square later on? If so, can you get other details using the method? I've tried using the `dir` function but that doesn't show tkinter details. If you don't understand, have these examples.

```py
id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill='green', outline='') # could i get the fill colour or outline later on?
square_colour = # colour
print(square_colour)
```

```py
id = canvas.create_text(250, 250, anchor='c', justify='c', text='foo bar', font=('Arial', 30)) # could i get some of these details?
id_state = # state
print(id_state)
```

Comment: Similarly `canvas.itemcget(id, 'fill')` will give you the colour.

Comment: Thanks for the link and solution!